# Show menu on all views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a View which displays horizontal menu on top.

I want to show this menu on all the Views.

How to call this menu view from another view?

I tried copying all the menu View code and pasting into _Layout.cshtml, but it is not working as the menu view has a controller associated with it.

Comment: You can use `@Html.Action()` in your Layout (to call a controller method that returns a partial view containing the menu items)

Comment: @StephenMuecke So first I will have to create a partial view?

Comment: Yes, So you might have a `public ActionResult Menu()` in a controller that initializes you collection of menu items which you then pass to a partial view to generate the html, and that method would `return PartialView(model)`. Then in the layout, use `@Html.Action("Menu", "yourController")`. You should also decorate the method with the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute so it can't be called directly (only via another view)

Comment: Have you got what you wanted ?